# evaluate EL expression within String value

Tags: jsf, el

Is it possible to evaluate an el-expression that is saved within a String value for instance in a managed bean variable?

In short: **Is double evaluation possible?**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bean")
@ViewScoped
public class Bean 
{
    private final String name = "bar";
    private final String nameEl = "foo #{bean.name} foo #{bean.name}";

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getNameEl()
    {
        return this.nameEl;
    }
}

<h:outputText value="#{bean.nameEl}" escape="false"/>
```

The output is: *foo #{bean.name} foo #{bean.name}*

and wished output should be: *foo bar foo bar*

**Idea:**

An el function could solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Application#evaluateExpressionGet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#evaluateExpressionGet%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) to evaluate a string as an EL expression and get the outcome.

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Object result = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, nameEL, Object.class);
// ...
```

In OmniFaces, this is also available in [`Faces`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/util/Faces.html) class.

```
Object result = Faces.evaluateExpressionGet(nameEL);
// ...
```

Comment: This is also possible for multiple occurences of el-expressions and other text content between them? Sorry my example was not good enough for the use case. Will edit question.

Comment: Did not knew this thought it is for retrieving a single instance with a single el expression. Thanks for that quick answer. I had the idea to save a cdn resource base url into database description columns with rich-html content. But this could be a security risk even if its not public since functions could be called. But that information is still great to know.

Comment: The security risk is indeed very high if `nameEL` is manipulatable by enduser. It would allow endusers execute arbitrary EL expressions.